# Is PHP possible in a Facebook Page post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to know if a PHP script can be executed within a Facebook post on a Facebook page.

What I am trying to do is schedule a post, write some text and include a PHP echo code which will show a recent statistics number, published on another website.

If there's another option to do so, please, share with us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can´t execute ANY code in a Facebook post. Not PHP, not JavaScript. If you want to schedule a post, you will have to add the final text. You can also schedule the post on your own though, and post it with a cron job and some new data.